# Deallocate memory with free() does not work

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

Here is a small program which fills some arrays and prints its content on the screen:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    double **plist;
    int plistSize;
} ParticleList;

void sendPar(int *n, int np){
    // allocate memory for struct pl
    ParticleList pl;

    // allocate memory  for ParticleList np times
    pl.plist = malloc(sizeof(ParticleList) * np);

    // allocate memory for lists of size n[k]
    for(int k=0; k<np; k++){
        pl.plist[k] = malloc(sizeof(double) * n[k]);
    }

    // write some data to the list
    for(int k=0; k<np; k++){
        for(int l=0; l<n[k]; l++){
            pl.plist[k][l] = 100000*k+100*l;
        }
        pl.plistSize = n[k];
    }

    // print data to check
    for(int k=0; k<np; k++){
        printf("Listsize: %d\n", n[k]);
        for(int l=0; l<n[k]; l++){
            printf("Processor %d, Entry %d, Value %lf\n", k, l, pl.plist[k][l]);
        }
    }

    free(pl.plist);
}

int main(){
    int np = 3;

    int n[np];
    n[0] = 2;
    n[1] = 4;
    n[2] = 7;

    sendPar(n, np);
}
```

This is the output:

```
Listsize: 2
Processor 0, Entry 0, Value 0.000000
Processor 0, Entry 1, Value 100.000000
Listsize: 4
Processor 1, Entry 0, Value 100000.000000
Processor 1, Entry 1, Value 100100.000000
Processor 1, Entry 2, Value 100200.000000
Processor 1, Entry 3, Value 100300.000000
Listsize: 7
Processor 2, Entry 0, Value 200000.000000
Processor 2, Entry 1, Value 200100.000000
Processor 2, Entry 2, Value 200200.000000
Processor 2, Entry 3, Value 200300.000000
Processor 2, Entry 4, Value 200400.000000
Processor 2, Entry 5, Value 200500.000000
```

If I now want to deallocate the memory, using `free(pl)` does not work. I tried also `free(pl.plist)` which does work. But than I have still memory of `plistSize` which is not deallocated. What is the right thing to free the memory here?

Comment: `pl.plist = malloc(sizeof(ParticleList) * np);`...emmm..how exactly?

Comment: How are you judging that the `free()` does not work?  I see nothing in the program itself that could tell you so.

Comment: Hint: When `free` crashes it is a sign of bad memory management elsewhere in your code, before the call to `free`.

Comment: @Samuel  Do you understand yourself what you are doing? plist has type double **. Why are you using sizeof( ParticleList ) to allocate memory?

Comment: Is there a reason you use `double` in the structure? You're not using floating-point values, only integer values.

Comment: I already answered this in a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41676986/584518). Then you run off to write this program, which is the same nonsense all over. Why ask questions if you don't listen when people answer?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Because I do not know it better. Please give me advice if it is wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is just an example. Later I need `double`

Comment: @Samuel In your struct you defined `plist` as a double pointer (a pointer to a pointer)!

Answer (score 2):

This memory allocation

```
pl.plist = malloc(sizeof(ParticleList) * np);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

does not make sense. I think you mean

```
pl.plist = malloc( sizeof( double * ) * np);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The last statement in this loop

```
// write some data to the list
for(int k=0; k<np; k++){
    for(int l=0; l<n[k]; l++){
        pl.plist[k][l] = 100000*k+100*l;
    }
    pl.plistSize = n[k];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

also does not make sense because the scalar object `pl.plistSize` is overwritten in each iteration of the outer loop.

To free the allocated memory you can write

```
for(int k=0; k<np; k++){
    free( pl.plist[k] )
}

free( pl.plist );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pl is a variabile declared statically which contains a pointer to a memory location. It is the array in the structure that needs to be freed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see it, you're leaving each `pl.plist[k]` allocated, leading to the memory leak.

Once you've `free()`-d `pl.plist`, there will be no way you can free the individual `pl.plist[k]`s, so the deallocation has to be in reverse order of allocation.

First free each `pl.plist[k]`s, then, free up the `pl.plist`  itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you misunderstand how `malloc` and `free` works.

The variable `pl` and its member `plistSize` are not allocated by you. It's allocated by the compiler when it compiles your code. You should not try to free it.

Only `free` what you `malloc`.

Comment: but `pl.plist` _is_ `malloc()`-ed, right?

Comment: Where's he trying to free `pl` or `plistSize`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger as said by OP in the question text, I also missed at first read. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes `pl.plist` is allocated with `malloc` so it should be free'd with `free`. But it *is* a little unclear exactly what the OP is asking.